# Realm object is not updated immediately?

Tags: android, realm

I have a fragment A which implements `RealmChangeListener`, you can go from fragment A to fragment B. On fragment B you can change some data, and then on `popBackStack()` / `backPressed` i want fragment A to reflect changes which has been made on fragment B. Is it clear?

The scenario

1. Fragment A (displays customer info)
2. Fragment B (user change eg customer name)
3. Back pressed
4. Fragment A - show new customer name

But in the last step I see only old customer name. When I go again to Fragment B finally I can see the new name, then on another backpressed to fragment A I also see the new name.

Question: Why I am not able to display new name immediately after FIRST returning from fragment B to fragment A?

If you want to see some code, please feel free to ask me.

**EDIT**

No, it's not because I'm not updating the UI... After navigating back to fragment A, realm is queried again to gain new data.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fragment lifecycle and what happens when you navigate to a new fragment?

Comment: @TimCastelijns  Sure... I've check that the method which calls realm query is called after pop stack...

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem you are having by the sounds of it.

- Fragment A is being created and the UI is being populated with the data from your Realm object X.
- You then navigate to Fragment B and updated the Realm object X data
- You then navigate back to Fragment A and the UI has not reflected the changes you made to Realm object X on Fragment B.

The solution is you need to update the UI to reflect the changes you had made to Realm object X. You can do this in this in the onResume() method for Fragment A. Here you want to read the new data from Realm object X and update the UI accordingly.

In short, your data object has been updated it's just you have not displayed this new data as you have most likely populated the UI in the onCreate() method for Fragment A. This won't be called again when you navigate back to Fragment A from Fragment B.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but thats no the case. I call realm query to get latest version of object X when navigate from fragment B back to A

Comment: @kristyna Yes it happens. As realm is taking time to save before the data gets saved your Fragment B got created. I am facing this issue hope you might have idea now. I am solving it temporarily using delay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the RealmChangeListener in `onCreateView()` and detach it in `onDestroyView()`, but the problem is that when you add the new fragment on top of the other, `onDestroyView()` will be called.

So your RealmChangeListener will not be called. You should reinitialize the query in `onCreateView()` before you add the RealmChangeListener to it.

Also, make sure you retain a field reference to your results.